# What is the best approach to have an ajax form and table in the same page without the need to refresh?

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit, form-submit, ajaxform

What is the best approach to have a form and a table in the same page, where the form has a submit button (ajaxsubmit) that saves the data in database and table should display the data without the need to refresh the page?

I have tried to call $.load to get the table, but some problems occurred due to the problem that $.load function finishes after document.ready

So shall i use iframe? or create an xml file and read the data into table?

Comment: What problems are you having with `$.load()`? As it stands now, your question is very vague.

Comment: The problem is that document.ready is executed before the $.load function therefore the code in document.ready is not applied on the loaded html, thanks

Comment: @malkawi that's why `.live` and `.delegate` and also the new `.on` were invented.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this explanation of jQuery's ajaxForm and ajaxSubmit: http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/ajaxform-and-ajaxsubmit-options/

Comment: thats great thanks, but how would i load the table of data after the form is submitted, shall use an iframe and reload it in the callback of the ajaxsubmit?

Comment: The whole point of doing Ajax in the first place is that you don't need to use an iframe. In the callback that you provide to ajaxsubmit, you update the dom with the data that you get back.

Answer (score 0):

To execute code after the `$.load()` method has completed you need to place it in the `callback` of the call to `load()`.

For example:

```
$("#myElement").load(
    '/location/of-target.html',
    function(data) {
        // put code here to execute after the load has completed.
        // for example to append a specific div.
        $(data).find("#myDiv").appendTo("#containerDiv");
    }
);
```

[**Further reading here**](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: but i cant execute the same function in the callback and document.ready otherwise, the code code bind to a click will be executed twice on click, right?